# Debugging OS 1053 The service did not respond to start or control in a timely fashion

Tags: database, windows, oracle, windows-services

During Oracle 21c database creation with DBCA OS 1053(sreenshot below) "OracleService{SID}" occurs. Tried adjusting ServicesPipeTimeout registry but it seems to take no effect as timeout occurs instantly. What could be checked to gain more insight into this problem? Couldn't find anything regarding the error in dbca log.

I had to go for "set up software only" in oracle installer because of "INS-30014: Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS". Some people reported that disabling network helps with this issue but I am working on a remote VM so it doesn't seem to be an option for me.

System: Windows Server 2016 Standard[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that too long DNS name was causing the issue(above 15 chars). After making it shorter, managed to perform installation and services work correctly.